# I have a bootstrap/css + wordpress scope issue

Tags: php, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, footer

In this particular page: http://web.patrick-diaz.com/WS-demo/2018/04/11/get-ready-for-summer-with-lesson/ my footer is failing to load correctly.

I am losing my footer bootstrap formatting for some reason and I am unsure why all of my columns and bootstrap formatting fail to load here. I can't figure out how to firebug the issue and find out why my css doesn't kick in. Anybody out there have any ideas what is happening in this footer?

Comment: I Chrome in the inspector, I see the following: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)`. I guess something is wrong with your PHP?

Comment: You are not getting the composer css file

Comment: I'm not doing anything different in this page with the footer than other pages where it works which is why I'm confused.

Comment: Luis, do you know what the css file title is?